# How to add a custom Sent Action for a custom NSControl (NSView, NSButton) in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder, target-action

I want to define a custom `NSControl` (or `NSView`), now the problem is how to add a *Sent Action* to it.

[image: Sent Actions]

As shown in the image, here are one or more *Sent Actions* for a control in the Connections inspector, for a `NSButton`, here's only one action, for a `NSTableView`, here are two actions.

**How can I add a new action for my custom control so that it too is listed here?**

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. The docs for `NSControl` define `action` as `var action: Selector? { get set }`. I tried subclassing `NSControl` and adding a similar property `otherAction` with the exact same signature, but it doesn't show up on Interface Builder...

Comment: I need to know this too ;) Had very little success googling this.